# Mongoose query user graph

Tags: mongoose

I have a user like

```
name : {
  type : String
},
organizations : [{
  type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  ref : 'Organization'
}]
```

and an organization like :

```
name : {
  type : String
},
members : [
  user : {
    type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref : 'User'
  },
  role : {
    type : String
  }
]
```

If i want to get every User a User can reach, say all the Users in the member list of his organizations, how do i do a query (populating the Users would be nice)?

To get all organizations i thought about:

`Organization.find({ '_id' : { $in: user.organizations } }).exec(function (err, organizations) { });`

I would like to avoid multiple queries, any help is appreciated!

Comment: would be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with a query for all organizations the user is in, populating all account fields and merging them into one array which i send as a response:

```
Organization.find({ '_id' : { $in: userOrganizations } }).populate('owner').populate('members.user').exec(function (err, organizations) {

    var accounts = [];

    organizations.forEach(function (organization) {
        organization.members.forEach(function (member) {
            accounts.push(member.user);
        });

        accounts.push(organization.owner);
    });

    res.send(accounts);
});
```